# Unable to create new Product in Magento 2.3.x (Blank Page)

Tags: php, nginx, magento2, centos7

I have recently installed Magento 2.3.5-p1/2.3.4 with sample data (different versions to solve this problem) and everything seems to work fine in frontend or admin panel. However, if I try to create new customer, or new product, or view current pages I have, or themes option in admin panel I get a blank page.

**1. Admin > Content > Pages**

[image]

.

**2. Admin > Catalog > Products**

[image]

**3. Admin > Catalog > Categories**

[image]

I don't have any errors in Nginx logs, however I see following type of errors in `system.log` which I believe should be ignored as thats what I found on the internet.

> [2020-07-13 05:52:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
> 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs',
> because the latter doesn't exist [] []

I have already for help on several other forums but none was able to help, so I am finally posting here. I hope someone can guide me.

**UPDATE:**

**Affected page are:**

```
Admin > Customers > All Customers > Add New Customer
Admin > Catalog > Product
Admin > Catalog > Categories

Admin > Content > Themes
Admin > Content > Configuration
Admin > Content > Pages
Admin > Content > Blocks
```

**Not Affected in these tabs:**

```
Admin > Content > Schedule
Admin > Content > Widgets
```

Comment: Are any core modules disabled? `php bin/magento module:status` to check

Comment: None, fresh installation, however I disabled CSP module, but even if i install fresh and without disabling it i have issues as explained above in Question. But here are the current modules: https://pastebin.com/raw/Cz2c2jgE

Comment: The module configuration looks fine to me. Did you check the web console? Maybe some js components can't load. `F12` to open console, should work in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @L.Gerhardt yes i have checked the console there is no error other than 404 pagespeed file, but it has nothing to do with it even if i disable page speed. My nginx config is: https://pastebin.com/raw/b1qXjaWB

Comment: I definitely never experienced something like this. Last thing I would recommend checking is the var/reports folder in Magento and nginx log files. I'm sadly not too experienced with nginx myself. Wish you best luck to identify the issue.

Comment: already pasted he log content in question :(, btw do I need to do something in settings in order to activate theme or product section? if, then maybe that might be the cause? if not then even I don't know whats the issue.

Comment: Custom theme can be activated in the admin panel, but that should not be necessary on a fresh installation. It could be that some layout files are missing / corrupted - debugging the xml configuration files can be a real pain though. These are all just guesses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was with ngx_pagespeed module, I disabled Page Speed and now it works absolutely fine without any errors.

I added following line to nginx configuration file.

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.conf
pagespeed   off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable php display errors in index.php
Simply the code below to the top of index.php and create products or pages

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I have added this `<root>/index.php` and erased cache, refreshed page, but catalog/product is blank, and no errors on page or js console.

Comment: yes. I have also tried to install it via composer/github/file but its same. deployed static-content etc. I don't know if it is due to Nginx. here is my config: https://pastebin.com/raw/b1qXjaWB

Comment: can you try remove deny all from this line location ~ /\. { deny all; } and add your ip location ~ /\. { allow your_ip }. If still not working, try remove all deny alls from this file and try. Don't forget reload nginx after changes.